# Nodejs event listener query. Process.on()

Tags: node.js, express

I was working with event emitters and wrote following code for testing purpose.
The following code works for the first time API hit comes, but fails after that.

```
 var express = require('express');
var pid = process.pid;
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/test',function (req,res) {
console.log("Hello I am in test");
process.on('testing',function () {
    return res.
            status(200).
            send("sucess");
    console.log("KUkar is here");
});
kukkar();   
});

function kukkar () {
    for(var i=0;i<10;i++) {
        if(i>=9) {
            process.emit('testing');
        }
    }
}
app.use('/api', router);

var server = app.listen(3000,function () {
        console.log('Listening on port !', server.address().port);
        console.log(`started process ${pid}`);  
    });
```

Why this code successfully works first time but failes after that?

Comment: what error u found?

Comment: may be u are getting ` EADDRINUSE` error, might be your app port is working in background. Kill and then restart your app.